# What SVN command can I use to see the branch I'm currently using?

Tags: svn

I generally use Subclipse, but there's some wonkiness in my code right now and I want to do some sanity checks from the command line. Thanks to Subclipse, I can usually see the branches I'm using in Eclipse's Package Explorer window.

[image: screenshot of branch information in Eclipse]

**What command can I use from the command line to see the branch I'm currently using?**

Resources I tried before Stack Overflow include [the SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.whatis.html), [this list of commands](https://www.forge.funambol.org/scdocs/ddUsingSVN_command-line) and [this other list of commands](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/Subversion.html). I didn't find anything that would let me passively look at branch information (as opposed to making some sort of active branch modification, which is not what I want).

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Try the following:

```
svn info
```

This will give you the URL your workspace is a checkout of, relative to where you are in the workspace. You should be able to see the branch in the URL.

Comment: Argh! I saw the description "Display information about file or directory. (Date modified, author, revision, path in repository.) Can not specify a URL." and skipped that one. Should've just tried it. Thanks. Upvotes to all because you all were probably typing at the same time; accepting this one because it has the best description and was _technically_ first.

Comment: @Lord Torgamus nice sluggy avatar btw

Comment: Heh, thank you. I always wondered if anyone got the reference.

Answer (score 19):

With some regex, you can get just the branch name:

```
svn info | grep '^URL:' | egrep -o '(tags|branches)/[^/]+|trunk' | egrep -o '[^/]+$'
```

Answer (score 5):

'svn info' from https://edoras.sdsu.edu/doc/svn-book-html-chunk/svn.ref.svn.c.info.html

The branch is what shows up in the URL below:

```
$ svn info foo.c
Path: foo.c
Name: foo.c
URL: http://svn.red-bean.com/repos/test/foo.c
Repository Root: http://svn.red-bean.com/repos/test
Repository UUID: 5e7d134a-54fb-0310-bd04-b611643e5c25
Revision: 4417
Node Kind: file
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: sally
Last Changed Rev: 20
Last Changed Date: 2003-01-13 16:43:13 -0600 (Mon, 13 Jan 2003)
Text Last Updated: 2003-01-16 21:18:16 -0600 (Thu, 16 Jan 2003)
Properties Last Updated: 2003-01-13 21:50:19 -0600 (Mon, 13 Jan 2003)
Checksum: d6aeb60b0662ccceb6bce4bac344cb66
```

Answer (score 5):

`svn info` will tell you the origin of your working copy. From that you can tell the branch.